# Samsung s7edge- can't open attachments on emails

Tags: samsung, attachments

I'm having recent trouble opening up PDf and other types of files on my
S7. It was never an issue. I've tried freeing some storage, cleaning out the cache, and also one suggestion was to go into default settings in Applications.
can anyone suggest something more specific.My default for internet is AOL

PS. If I go to downloads and open an old pdf file , no problem, it opens

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I figured it out. I deleted my aol account and re-installed it.
All attachments open up fine. So if its not your default settings or low
storage, try that .